# Bounding $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c}$ beyond concavity

Tags: convex-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

#### Problem

Consider three positive numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$.
As the function $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is concave, for any $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$ with $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 1$ and $\alpha,\, \beta,\, \gamma \ge 0$:
\begin{equation}
    \alpha \sqrt{a} + \beta \sqrt{b} + \gamma \sqrt{c} \le \sqrt{\alpha a + \beta b + \gamma c}.
\end{equation}

Can we find other families of upperbound? By "family of upperbound" I mean a set of points $u = f(a,b,c, \alpha, \beta, \gamma)$  linear in $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $\alpha \sqrt{a} + \beta \sqrt{b} + \gamma \sqrt{c} \le \sqrt{u}$.

#### Intuition

The convex combination $\alpha \sqrt{a} + \beta \sqrt{b} + \gamma \sqrt{c} $ may be view as a convex combination of two convex comibations:
\begin{equation}
    \theta \left(\omega_{A} \sqrt{a} + (1-\omega_{A}) \sqrt{c}\right) + (1-\theta) \left(\omega_{B} \sqrt{b} + (1-\omega_{B}) \sqrt{c}\right),
\end{equation}
with $\omega_A, \, \omega_B, \, \theta \in [0,1]$.

Can't we use some property of the derivative $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ to produce better upperbound than just taking twice the concavity property?

I would like to add second order terms in the expression of $u$, e.g., $(\alpha^2 - \beta\gamma)a$.

Comment: $$f(a,b,c,\alpha, \beta,\gamma) = \alpha^2a + \beta^2b + \gamma^2c + 2(\alpha\beta\sqrt{ab} + \alpha\gamma\sqrt{ac} + \beta\gamma\sqrt{bc})$$ gives an unbeatably close upper bound. ;)

Comment: Indeed pretty tight, but it does help much. I was expecting a convex, or quadratic, combination of a, b and c. And get rid of the square roots

Comment: Well, it meets every condition you've given in your problem statement, and it cannot be improved upon, so it is the best you are going to get until you explain what other requirements you have that it doesn't meet.

Comment: I've edited the problem, thanks. I am looking for a function linear in $a$, $b$ and $c$.